# Веб программист является кодером?

Tags: веб-программирование

Кодер — это человек, который пишет код по четко определенным спецификациям и выбранным заранее алгоритмам

Программист же обычно сам разрабатывает алгоритм, а затем выполняет работу кодера.

Не нравится мне термин "кодер".
Но тогда выходит что веб программисты - это кодеры, а не программисты, или я не прав?

Comment: Не знаю как по вашему, но программист - разрабатывает ПО для разных вычислительных систем, а это значит, пишет скрипт-код. А вот кодер, я бы вынес это в Кодирование/Декодирование алгоритмов. также как и шифратор - Шифрует/Дешифрует.

Comment: Зависит от образования и стажа. Малолетний шалопай конечно же является кодером. Взрослый же, уважающий себя, дядька не будет называть себя кодером. Только если для в шутку, для иронии

Comment: "_Но тогда выходит что веб программисты - это кодеры_". А почему вы считаете, что в web не надо строить архитектуру будущего приложения, придумывать различные алгоритмы, перед тем как их закодировать ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ответ зависит от многих причин. Один и тот же человек, например, может быть программистом на пивзаводе и кодером в яндексе. Опять же, спецификации редко, сильно редко бывают настолько подробными, что сразу понятно что писать, как и в каком порядке. На самом деле проще в таком случае сразу писать код. Поэтому даже при сильно подробном ТЗ всегда нужно думать над архитектурой и алгоритмами.

Ну и да, "кодер" обычно воспринимается как нечто обидное. Воспринимается как грузчик на складе, чья задача - таскать ящики не думая. Советую избегать употребление этого термина при общении с коллегами.